# miktex 2.9.7347 issues

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I have done a fresh install of MiKTeX on my new computer and have been experiencing numerous issues I never encountered on my previous install (2.9.6821). Is anyone else experiencing difficulties using the latest version?

An example issue is the compiler saying a package is not found even though the "on-the-fly" installer just installed it, as an example: (note I have tried numerous uninstall/re-install/reboot combinations, and the specific TeX files I am trying to compile work just fine on my older computer)

[image]

Comment: did you check your internet connection? Did you try to run MikTeX as an administrator? As far as I know, MikTeX is related to TeXLive. Since the latter is in preparation of the new release you might encounter such issues when you update your packages

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try installing the very latest (2.9.7351)?

Comment: Are you using subfiles or the import package?

Comment: @Bernard the 2.9.7351 installer shows up as 2.9.7347 in the MiKTeX Console

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the document uses a modified version of [erdc](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/erdc?lang=en) , yes subfiles, subcaption, and many more are used

Comment: Try if the patch here helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531364/2388

Comment: I'll mail the author of import tomorrow if you confirm the patch works

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the patch appeared to let the compiler make more progress, however now there are new errors about a header/footer figure which does exists. If I remove the figure it then complains about main.toc 

`
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{} % clear existing style
% header
\fancyhead[C]{\begin{tabular}{L{3.08in} R{3.08in}}
  \makecell[l]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{BAR_Logo_Transparent}} &
`

Comment: try copying import.sty from your older setup and put it in the folder with your document (as a test)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the old setup did not rely on import so I didn't have an old instance to copy. However, I did copy over the **subfiles.sty** and **subfiles.cls** into my test folder and that worked properly with the new setup. For reference both of the old files had `2018/07/31 Federico Garcia, Gernot Salzer` as the date and author, whereas the new files (that aren't working for me) are dated  `2020/02/14 v1.6 Multi-file projects (package)`