# File 'main.aux' not found

Tags: errors

I'm just a beginner on Latex. I was reading on managing big projects and how I can use the import package to make this easier so I gave it a try. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter{}
\import{./}{title.tex}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter{}
\chapter{Ch1}
\import{./}{Ch1.tex}

\backmatter{}

\end{document}
```

It's very simple, I didn't really expect there to be any trouble but when I run it I get the error message :

> File 'main.aux' not found

Now, I've looked up this error in google. And so far I've only found that this error occurs when there is something wrong in the preamble, but my preamble only includes a simple package so idk what's actually going on here. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: `import` is not a "simple" package.  it contains quite sophisticated and complicated code to reset search pathes. For your example you don't need it. Simply \input{title} and \input{Ch1} should work fine. Beside this it sounds as if you have the version which has a bug, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531364/2388.

Comment: You don't need the import package to use \import (core TeX).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But if I use \input it also shows the preamble of the file I \inputted